# How to set default values for Angular 2 component properties?

Tags: angular, typescript

When writing Angular 2.0 components, how does one set default values for properties?

For example - I want to set `foo` to `'bar'` by default, but the binding might immediately resolve to `'baz'`. How does this play out in the lifecycle hooks?

```
@Component({  
    selector: 'foo-component'
})
export class FooComponent {
    @Input()
    foo: string = 'bar';

    @Input()
    zalgo: string;

    ngOnChanges(changes){
          console.log(this.foo);
          console.log(changes.foo ? changes.foo.previousValue : undefined);
          console.log(changes.foo ? changes.foo.currentValue : undefined);
    }
}
```

Given the following templates, this is what I expect the values would be. Am I wrong?

```html
<foo-component [foo] = 'baz'></foo-component>
```

Logged to console:

```
'baz'
'bar'
'baz'
```

```html
<foo-component [zalgo] = 'released'></foo-component>
```

Logged to console:

```
'bar'
undefined
undefined
```

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: @BryanRayner the way currently console's are getting printed are correct..what is the problem which you facing?

Comment: I am not currently facing a problem, just seeking clarification on the intended behavior. When I didn't find the answer to my curiosity, I decided I would ask the question in case others had the same desire for clarity.

Comment: In your example you are missing the parenthesis on the @Input()

Comment: For those who are still searching for answer there is "Input setter coercion" in angular official documentation where you are working with getters and setters of an input.
https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#input-setter-coercion

Answer (score 187, accepted):

That is interesting subject. 
You can play around with two lifecycle hooks to figure out how it works: `ngOnChanges` and `ngOnInit`.

Basically when you set default value to `Input` that's mean it will be used only in case there will be no value coming on that component.
And the interesting part it will be changed before component will be initialized.

Let's say we have such components with two lifecycle hooks and one property coming from `input`.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'cmp',
})
export class Login implements OnChanges, OnInit {
  @Input() property: string = 'default';

  ngOnChanges(changes) {
    console.log('Changed', changes.property.currentValue, changes.property.previousValue);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Init', this.property);
  }

}
```

**Situation 1**

*Component included in html without defined `property` value*

As result we will see in console:
`Init default`

That's mean `onChange` was not triggered. Init was triggered and `property` value is `default` as expected.

**Situation 2**

*Component included in html with setted property* `<cmp [property]="'new value'"></cmp>`

As result we will see in console:

`Changed`  `new value`  `Object {}`

`Init`  `new value`

And this one is interesting. Firstly was triggered `onChange` hook, which setted `property` to `new value`, and previous value was **empty object**! And only after that `onInit` hook was triggered with new value of `property`.

Comment: Is there any links to the official docs for this behavior? Would be good to understand the logic and reasoning behind this, also be able to track what the behavior is per version.

Comment: I have not seen such info, all above is my own investigation. I think you can find more answers if you will read compiled js files

Comment: I was looking for documentation on the `@Input` having default values.  @slicepan has a link to the docs for the component lifecycle, but I did not see a default value used in the documentation.

Comment: @nycynik  simply use this for default values: `@Input() someProperty = 'someValue';`

Comment: You are lifesaver. This made my head hurt, while was upgrading from AngularJS app to Angular 7.x

Answer (score 14):

Here is the best solution for this. (ANGULAR All Version)

**Addressing solution**: To ***set a default value for @Input variable***. If ***no value passed** to that input variable then It will take the default value*.

I have provided solution for this kind of similar question. You can find the full solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60202550/12466554)

```
export class CarComponent implements OnInit {
  private _defaultCar: car = {
    // default isCar is true
    isCar: true,
    // default wheels  will be 4
    wheels: 4
  };

  @Input() newCar: car = {};

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {

   // this will concate both the objects and the object declared later (ie.. ...this.newCar )
   // will overwrite the default value. ONLY AND ONLY IF DEFAULT VALUE IS PRESENT

    this.newCar = { ...this._defaultCar, ...this.newCar };
   //  console.log(this.newCar);
  }
}
```

Comment: That means default @Input() value of {} is never used, right? You might as well skip it:
  @Input() newCar: car;

Comment: "the best" is relative. You are setting a default value yes but when the input changes you dont set it again.