# @Input array undefined

Tags: angular, input

I have a child component implemented in the parent component where I pass data to the child component. But when I try to use the array, I always get an undefined.

How can I fix this?

```
export class SelectionFieldComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() data: any[] = [];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.data);
  }
}
```

parent.component.html

```
<app-selection-field [data]="units"></app-selection-field>
```

EDIT: I see the data on the site, but also get the error.

Comment: can you create a small example on stackblitz.com?

Comment: can you show the parent code and the place where you say you pass the data to the child?

Comment: How is `units` assigned content?

Comment: units: string[] = ['mm', 'kg', 'stk'];

Comment: Please provide a stackblitz which reproduces your issue. Now seeing how you assign data, your code should work fine. And you say `I also get the error`, what error would that be? since you also say that you can see the data.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-grx2rf

Comment: When you provide a stackblitz, please make sure that it is a **working** stackblitz. Here is a **working** stackblitz, and we can see that the code you provided works just like it should: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jp8che?file=app/form-field-overview-example.ts

Answer (score 2):

It might depend on how do you create your data array.

- **If it's from observable:**

**1st solution** to implement `OnChanges` interface. Because observable gets `data` asynchronous and just then parses to the component. So you might not be able to print `data` in `ngOnInit()` method, because `data` might come just after component initialization.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes['data']) {
        this.data = changes['data'].currentValue;
    }
}
```

**2nd solution**
Use `setTimeout()` method, but it's very bad practice.

---

- **If it's a static (hard coded) array**

It should work as it is. Or try to use same methods which is above.

---

Also please read about [component lifecycle](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

Comment: well, OP says the data is assigned `units: string[] = ['mm', 'kg', 'stk'];` so async shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: Also there is already answered same type of  question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39219751/5272951 @AJT_82

Comment: what does that question have to do with this question?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't included any alises. So your parent property binding of parent should be **data**

```
<app-parent [data]="your-array"></app-parent>
```

In your child component, as you defined

```
@Input() data:any[] = []
```

Comment: I did, but I forgot to write it in my question. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out where the error comes from. In my parent component I have multiple selection-fields and one of them don't received the data correctly so it is undefined. I thought that was the selection field we are talking about. After a quick if/else it is working now. Thank you all!